# perl - map not working, "Can't use string ... as a HASH ref"

Tags: perl, hash, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max);
use DateTime;
use JSON;

use DBI;

...

my @names = @{ select_users_to_update('last_name') };

sub select_users_to_update {
    my ( $self, $column ) = @_;

    my $sql = qq{
        SELECT DISTINCT `$column`
        FROM `db_name`
        WHERE `first_name` IS NULL
    };
    my $rows = $self->{dbh}->selectall_arrayref( $sql, { Slice => {} } );
    my @fields = map { $_->{$column} } @$rows;

    return \@fields;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Can't use string ("last_name") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at update_hpcdb_people.pm line 51.
```

This code was taken from a different script, where it performed fine. I'm confused at perl's objection to the map command - what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Assuming the elided code includes something like this to connect to the database:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(....);
```

Then altering the call to `select_users_to_update` like this will do the trick:

```
my @names = @{ select_users_to_update( { dbh => $dbh }, 'last_name') };
```

The explanation follows.

The `select_users_to_update` subroutine expects its first argument (`$self`)  to be a reference to a Hash containing a `dbh` field whose value is the handle to the database connection.  You didn't pass any such thing to it; all you passed was the column name.

It's presumably from a program with a custom module, written as an object class, for handling the database stuff.  The `select_users_to_update` subroutine is written as a method of the class, so I'm guessing that code in the original program to do what you're trying to do would look something like this:

```
my $customObj = CustomClass->new( database parameters ... );
my @names = @{ $customObj->select_users_to_update('last_name') };
```

Since calling a subroutine using the method syntax `$someRef->subname` is the same as passing `$someRef` as the first argument, the reference in `$customObj` would become `$self` inside the subroutine.  As long as the constructor `CustomClass::new` populated `dbh` in the referenced Hash, it would work as designed.

But you don't have to replicate all that extra code if you don't need it and just want to use the one subroutine.  You can reuse it as-is with the code in the TL;DR above.

Alternatively, you could modify the subroutine slightly, so it just takes the unadorned database handle directly instead of looking for it inside a hashref:

```
my @names = @{ select_users_to_update( $dbh, 'last_name') };

sub select_users_to_update {
    my ( $dbh, $column ) = @_;
    ...
    my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref( $sql, { Slice => {} } );
    ...
}
```

And now instead of a method of a custom class, you have a standalone subroutine you can use with any old DBI object.